# Running through 2 tables gives me the wrong output

Tags: loops, lua

It's probably just me being a little bit nooby right now, but I am having some issues with adding some values from 2 separate tables into one, with the values from the first table as a key and the values from the second table as a value.

This may have some differences from "regular" lua, as it is a lua wrapper with some modifications.

Please note that I am in no way an expert in Lua, but learning as I go :-)

```
local Models = {
 ["NO"] = {
        ["Normal"] = {
            categories = { 3,4,5,6,7,8,9 },
        },
        ["Narrow"] = {
            categories = { 3,4,5,6,7,8,9 },
        },
    }
}
   local NumberDefinitions = {
        [0] = 0,
        [1] = 1,
        [2] = 2,
        [3] = 3,
        [4] = 4, 
        [5] = 5,
        [6] = 6,
        [7] = 7,
        [8] = 8,
        [9] = 9
    }
  local TextDefinitions = {
        ["A"] = 1,
        ["B"] = 2,
        ["C"] = 3,
        ["D"] = 4,
        ["E"] = 5,
        ["F"] = 6,    
        ["G"] = 7,
        ["H"] = 8,
        ["I"] = 9,
        ["J"] = 10,
        ["K"] = 11,
        ["L"] = 12,
        ["M"] = 13,
        ["N"] = 14,
        ["O"] = 15,
        ["P"] = 16,
        ["R"] = 17,
        ["S"] = 18,
        ["T"] = 19,
        ["U"] = 20,
        ["V"] = 21,
        ["W"] = 22,
        ["X"] = 23,
        ["Y"] = 24,
        ["Z"] = 25,
    }
local SetPlate = { 
     [1] = 24,
     [2] = 1,
     [3] = 6, 
     [4] = 5,
     [5] = 3,
     [6] = 2,
     [7] = 9
}
```

The expected output I am looking for would be

```
 3 24
    4 1
    5 6
    6 5
    7 3
    8 2
    9 9
```

Though, the output I am getting right now is

```
3 9
4 9
5 9 
6 9
7 9 
8 9
9 9
```

Running:

```
local PBG = PBG or {}

 for k,v in pairs(Models["NO"].Normal.Categories) do
   if !PBG[v] then 
     for _,val in ipairs(TDM_SetPlate) do
       PBG[v] = val
     end 
  end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code, I adjusted to your result:

```
local t_cat = Models["NO"].Normal.categories
 for i=1, #t_cat do
       if not PBG[i] then     
               PBG[i] = SetPlate[i]
               print( t_cat[i] ,PBG[i] )
        end
  end
```

this is what you need?

ps: lua is a case-sensitive language, and "categories"~="Categories"